# Updating a table using an IF condition

Tags: mysql

How do I update a table, such that values of one column is used to    calculate values of another column if a condition is met. For instance

```
UPDATE table
IF column1>8000 
SET column2 =  (column1-8000)*1.5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `WHERE` clause and I think you should read [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `WHERE` clause like so:

```
UPDATE table
SET column2 = (column1-8000)*1.5
WHERE column1>8000;
```

`UPDATE` reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE table
SET column2 =  (column1-8000)*1.5
WHERE column1>8000

Cheers ;)